# Ansible seems to execute infinite loop

Tags: ansible, yaml, glusterfs

I wrote some roles for my home lab to setup a GlusterFS cluster.

But when I run it on my 2 nodes, some tasks get executed over and over again and it seems that it never ends.

Here is the log output (I cut it off at some point and also removed a lot of the * characters)

```
 ✘ user@pc  ~/ansible   feature/role-gluster  ansible-playbook -i inventories/playground/hosts.yaml site.yml -K
BECOME password: 

PLAY [storageservers] ******************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [include_role : gluster-node] *****

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [Create data1 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data2 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data2 partition] 
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data2 partition] 
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data2 partition] 
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data2 partition] *
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [Create data3 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data3 partition] 
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data3 partition] 
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data3 partition] 
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data3 partition] *
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Update apt-get repo and cache] ***
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node : Upgrade all apt packages] ********
changed: [node2]

changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node : Install GlusterFS] 
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node : Enable GlusterFS on Boot] ********
changed: [node2]
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node : Probe GlusterFS Nodes] *
changed: [node1] => (item=node1)
changed: [node2] => (item=node1)
changed: [node1] => (item=node2)
changed: [node2] => (item=node2)

TASK [gluster-node : Ensure Gluster brick and mount directories exist.] 
changed: [node1] => (item=/data1)
changed: [node2] => (item=/data1)
changed: [node1] => (item=/gluster_volume1)
changed: [node2] => (item=/gluster_volume1)

TASK [gluster-node : Configure Gluster volume.] *******
changed: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node : Ensure Gluster volume is mounted.] *************
changed: [node1]
changed: [node2]

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data1 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data2 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data2 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data3 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data3 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create default partitioning] *****

TASK [Create gluster volume for partition 1] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node] *****

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data1 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data2 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data2 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data3 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data3 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Update apt-get repo and cache] ***
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Upgrade all apt packages] ********
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Install GlusterFS] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Enable GlusterFS on Boot] ********
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Probe GlusterFS Nodes] *
changed: [node1] => (item=node1)
changed: [node2] => (item=node1)
changed: [node2] => (item=node2)
changed: [node1] => (item=node2)

TASK [gluster-node : Ensure Gluster brick and mount directories exist.] 
ok: [node1] => (item=/data1)
ok: [node2] => (item=/data1)
ok: [node1] => (item=/gluster_volume1)
ok: [node2] => (item=/gluster_volume1)

TASK [gluster-node : Configure Gluster volume.] *******
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node : Ensure Gluster volume is mounted.] *************
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data1 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data2 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data2 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data3 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data3 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data3 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create default partitioning] *****

TASK [Create gluster volume for partition 1] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node] *****

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [include_role : gluster-node-partition] 

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [Create data1 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data1 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data1 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data1 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data2 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data2 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data2 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data2 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data2 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [Create data3 partition] **********

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create data3 partition] 
ok: [node2]
ok: [node1]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create filesystem on data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Create mount point for data3 partition] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node-partition : Mount data3 partition] *
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Update apt-get repo and cache] ***
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Upgrade all apt packages] ********
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Install GlusterFS] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Enable GlusterFS on Boot] 
ok: [node1]
ok: [node2]

TASK [gluster-node : Probe GlusterFS Nodes] 
changed: [node1] => (item=node1)
changed: [node2] => (item=node1)
changed: [node1] => (item=node2)
changed: [node2] => (item=node2)

TASK [gluster-node : Ensure Gluster brick and mount directories exist.] 
ok: [node1] => (item=/data1)
ok: [node2] => (item=/data1)
ok: [node1] => (item=/gluster_volume1)
ok: [node2] => (item=/gluster_volume1)

TASK [gluster-node : Configure Gluster volume.] 
ok: [node1]


^C [ERROR]: User interrupted execution
```

I placed all the code here:
https://github.com/CodingSpiderFox/ansible-loop-problem

Answer (score 1):

I commited the fix to the Github repo. The problem was that a role was included recursively.

I split up the roles a bit to fix it.
Also discovered a lot of other issues with repeated task executions (not all of the fixed yet because I'm still learning how to structure my ansible tasks)